# Order of the youtube Playlist api

Tags: youtube-api

How can I get the order of the playlist api? I looked into [the doku](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)
and got all my playlist returned, however the order in which they are returned, doesn't match the order in which the are on the youtube channel?

Is there a possibility to get the list in the order of the youtube channel, or have an id property of in which order the playlists are?

Comment: there doesn't appear to be a sort option.

Comment: that's abdd and a real shortcoming of the api...

Comment: add it as an issue ?  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list

Comment: done: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7562&thanks=7562&ts=1442567810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the decomuntation again and again, and also the comments, I realized that this is not possible.

Issue

> https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7562&thanks=7562&ts=1442567810

was created in googles issu tracker.